# GET request, wait for external processes to complete before returning response

Tags: javascript, node.js, process, request

I am trying to solve a problem related with waiting for response inside `GET` request.
So the situation is following:

- user accesses an url
- script extracts data from url and spawns external process for to conduct the tasks
- once tasks are ready, external process communicates with web server that tasks have been completed and sends result
- result needs to be returned now

The problem i am having is, how to stop/wait inside `GET` request for the result from external source.

```
let tasks = {};

app.get('/spawner/:clientId/:otherId', (req, res) => {
    const { clientId, otherId } = req.params;
    let result = spawnTask(clientId, otherId);
    if(result === false) {
        res.json({
            message: "Another request already in progress.",
            status: false
        });
    }

    if(result === true) {
        /* WAIT HERE FOR RESULT */

        res.json({
            message: "Request has been completed.",
            status: true,
            file: tasks[clientId].file
        });

        delete tasks[clientId];
    }
});

const spawnTask = (clientId, otherId) => {
    if(clientId in tasks === true) {
        return false;
    }

    const child = spawn('node', ['./slave.js', 'other', clientId, otherId], {
        detached: true,
        stdio: [ 'ignore', out, err ]
    });

    child.unref();

    tasks[clientId] = {
        pid: child.pid,
        file: '',
        done: false
    };

    return true;
};

socket.on('result', (clientId, pid, data) => {
    if(clientId in tasks === true) {
        tasks[clientId].file = data;
        tasks[clientId].done = true;
    }
})
```

What i tried is:

```
if(result === true) {
    while(tasks[clientId].done === false) {}
    ...
}
```

but this only causes 100% cpu usage and script is overloaded.

Comment: Conditional variable is what you are looking for
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization)#Condition_variables_2

Comment: Are you sure that you want to make the user wait until the data has been received through a different connection? What if the socket never receives the data?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how promises work? (https://javascript.info/promise-basics)
This situation calls for something like a promise, where you would wait for the return and only continue with the next task when the promise can be resolved (or when an error occurs).

Comment: promise will be resolved in the same tread that will call resolve

Comment: can you show how promise can be implemented to it, if result is delivered by socket.io message

Comment: @Mevia you can call resolve in the https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_event_exit

Comment: yes but how to implement it, how to resolve it when message comes from socket.io

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it a **Promise** that you are looking for !?
please take a look at it:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

OR do a search for it and you'll find plenty of articles about it so you may study further.